# Code blocks C++ class constructor error

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to create the contructors for line but I keep getting this error even though this worked on the poolball class and was able to run before adding line.cpp and line.h. Also, this is code from class, and i have no idea why it is not compiling.

```
#include "Line.h"
Line::Line(){
}

Line::Line( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
}

void Line::setPos(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
}

void Line::draw( void ){
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma once

class Line{
public:
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2, y2;

    //constructor
    Line();
    Line( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    //methods
    void setPos(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
    void draw( void);
```

This is the error I get when trying to build and run

```
||=== Build: Debug in 10.19class (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|2|error: extra     qualification 'Line::' on member 'Line' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|2|error: 'Line::Line()' cannot be overloaded|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.h|10|error: with 'Line::Line()'|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|5|error: extra qualification 'Line::' on member 'Line' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|5|error: 'Line::Line(int, int, int, int)' cannot be overloaded|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.h|11|error: with 'Line::Line(int, int, int, int)'|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|9|error: extra qualification 'Line::' on member 'setPos' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|9|error: 'void Line::setPos(int, int, int, int)' cannot be overloaded|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.h|13|error: with 'void Line::setPos(int, int, int, int)'|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|12|error: extra qualification 'Line::' on member 'draw' [-fpermissive]|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|12|error: 'void Line::draw()' cannot be overloaded|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.h|14|error: with 'void Line::draw()'|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|13|error: expected '}' at end of input|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp||In constructor 'Line::Line(int, int, int, int)':|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|6|error: 'cout' is  not a member of 'std'|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|6|error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C++Projects\10.19class\Line.cpp|13|error: expected unqualified-id at end of input|
||=== Build failed: 16 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))   ===|
```

Comment: one thing you might consider  is to `#incluce <iostream>`, since you are using `std::cout`

Comment: this `void Line(void);` says a lot. You should go back and learn about default constructors and constructors initialization

Comment: That was me messing with it and not changing the code back. The original is above.

Comment: Line::sePos and setPos don't match and @Bobby is correct about #include <iostream>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error messages, and assuming the stuff below the dashes is the full contents of your header file, then your problem is that you're missing `};` at the end of your header file. You need to close your class definition with the close bracket and semicolon in your header, before you can implement the functions in your Line.cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

`void Line(void)` is not true,constructors have no return type and in parameter list you shouldn't write `void`,either.